# The environ package eats a space

Tags: spacing, environments

I am using the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/environ) package to collect the body of an environment to be used later. It appears that the `environ`environment gobbles the trailing space. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myenviron}{\BODY}
\begin{document}
A \begin{myenviron}B\end{myenviron} C

X\begin{myenviron}Y\end{myenviron}Z
\end{document}
```

gives me `A BC` and `XYZ`, but I would like `A B C` and `XYZ`. What is the proper way to get the trailing space back?

I just looked at the source code and the answer is on line 7

```
\environfinalcode{\ignorespacesafterend}
```

so I can fix the problem with `\environfinalcode{}`, but I would prefer a less global change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\environfinalcode` is executed if not overridden explicitly with the final optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myenviron}{\BODY}[]

\begin{document}
A \begin{myenviron}B\end{myenviron} C

X\begin{myenviron}Y\end{myenviron}Z
\end{document}
```

[image]